# How to create struts jquery link with confirmation alert box?

Tags: jquery, struts2, hyperlink, struts, alert

I want to create `<sj:a></sj:a>` link that after click will show first confirmation dialog box.

I tried with `<sj:dialog>` but it's doesnt works.
Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

```
sj:a 
    id="ajaxlink" 
    href="%{'#'}" 
    indicator="indicator" 
    onClickTopics="before" 
    button="true" 
    >
      click me
    </sj:a>


$.subscribe('before', function(event,data) {
   //do your condition check here
   if(condition){
       window.location="yourLocation";
   }
});
```